# How to choose between different paths for the same resource in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

I am writing a client that needs to access resource restparameter through three different paths. The paths are `resource/:resourceId/restparameter`, `restparameter/:restparameterId/restparameter` and `restmethod/:restmethodId/restparamter`. I have tried to do this by using `$location` but it doesn't work. For example when I try to access the restparameter through the `path:http://localhost:8085/output/#/restmethod/54/restparameter` the client calls only this: `GET http://localhost:8085/WSAT/multirestparameterManager/restparameter/restparameter`, which obviously responses 404 Not Found. I'm guessing that it doesn't go in the matching if, since it doesn't even try to call `GET http://localhost:8085/WSAT/multirestparameterManager/restmethod/restparameter` My controller is this:

```
WSAT.controller('restparameterCtrl',['$scope','$resource','$location','$route','$routeParams','popupService', 'restparameterFactory',
    function($scope,$resource, $location, $route,$routeParams,popupService, restparameterFactory, $window)
    {   $scope.$location = {};
        var result = $location.url();

        if(result.includes("restparameter")){var Restparameter = $resource('http://localhost\\:8085/WSAT/multirestparameterManager/restparameter/:restparameterId/restparameter/');  
        $scope.restparameters = Restparameter.get({restparameterId: $routeParams.restparameterId});}

        else if(result.includes("resource")){var Restparameter = $resource('http://localhost\\:8085/WSAT/multirestparameterManager/resource/:resourceId/restparameter/');  
        $scope.restparameters = Restparameter.get({resourceId: $routeParams.resourceId});}

        else if(result.includes("restmethod")){var Restparameter = $resource('http://localhost\\:8085/WSAT/multirestparameterManager/restmethod/:restmethodId/restparameter/');  
        $scope.restparameters = Restparameter.get({restmethodId: $routeParams.restmethodId});}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `paramDefaults` while creating `$resource`object.

If you want `:restparameterId` parameter should get from passed object,then you should tell the angular by passing the default parameter `{restparameterId:'@id'}`.

And the same for other.

Check [`$ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for more.

```
if (result.includes("restparameter")) {
    var Restparameter = $resource('multirestparameterManager/restparameter/:restparameterId/restparameter/',{restparameterId:'@id'});
    $scope.restparameters = Restparameter.get({ restparameterId: $routeParams.restparameterId });
} else if (result.includes("resource")) {
    var Restparameter = $resource('multirestparameterManager/resource/:resourceId/restparameter/',{resourceId:'@id'});
    $scope.restparameters = Restparameter.get({ resourceId: $routeParams.resourceId });
} else if (result.includes("restmethod")) {
    var Restparameter = $resource('multirestparameterManager/restmethod/:restmethodId/restparameter/',{restmethodId:'@id'});
    $scope.restparameters = Restparameter.get({ restmethodId: $routeParams.restmethodId });
}
```

Comment: The parameters is the problem here, because I've tried them separatly for it's specific path alone and the get method worked. I have a feeling that the if(){}else if() conditions are wrong, but I can't thing another logic to choose between the three paths.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameters while using $resource object.

```
var URL = 'http://localhost\\:8085/';
var Restparameter = $resource(URL +"WSAT/multirestparameterManager/:masterpath/:Id/restparameter/", "{Id:'@Id'}", {
    });

if (result.includes("restparameter")) {

    $scope.restparameters = Restparameter.get({ Id: $routeParams.restparameterId });

} else if (result.includes("resource")) {

    $scope.restparameters = Restparameter.get({ Id: $routeParams.resourceId });

} else if (result.includes("restmethod")) {

    $scope.restparameters = Restparameter.get({ Id: $routeParams.restmethodId });
}
```